# Python worker crashes when loading CSV file with many columns

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, correlation

I'm trying to load [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ltwg63jpm55845m/pivot.csv?dl=0) CSV file with many columns and calculate the correlation between columns using Spark.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics

conf = SparkConf()\
    .setAppName("Movie recommender")\
    .setMaster("local[*]")\
    .set("spark.driver.memory", "10g")\
    .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "4g")

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)


pivot = sc.textFile(r"pivot.csv")
header = pivot.first()
pivot = pivot.filter(lambda x:x != header)
pivot = pivot.map(lambda x:x.split()).cache()
corrs = Statistics.corr(pivot)
```

I get this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to run this with increased partitions. But the performance is really slow on my local machine that it's not actually working. Performance issue seems to be expected when the number of columns are high.

```
def extract_sparse(str_lst, N):
    if len(str_lst) == 0:
        return (0, {})
    else:
        keyvalue = {}
        length = len(str_lst)
        if length > N:
            length = N
        for i in range(length):
            if str_lst[i] != '': # not missing
                keyvalue[i] = float(str_lst[i])

        return (length, keyvalue)

pivot = sc.textFile(r"pivot.csv", 24)
header = pivot.first()
pivot = pivot.filter(lambda x:x != header)
pivot = pivot.map(lambda x:x.split(','))
pivot = pivot.map(lambda x: extract_sparse(x, 50000))
pivot = pivot.map(lambda x: Vectors.sparse(x[0], x[1]))
pivot = pivot.map(lambda x: x.toArray()).collect()
corrs = Statistics.corr(pivot)
```